# Como referenciar contenido de un div que contiene una tabla con pseudoclases al imprimir?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

He visto varios ejemplos en el foro para la carga de una `<link href="." rel="stylesheet" >` mediante javascript, he actualizado el post anterior,no cargaba porque el path del elemento no reconoce la ruta Content/printgeneral.css ni rutas absolutas con ~/Content/, cambié a ../Content/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function imprime() {    
                              
                //document.cookie = "printer=" + 1;
                var style = document.createElement("link");
                style.rel = "stylesheet";
                style.type = "text/css";
                style.href = "../Content/printgeneral.css";
                ///* Añadimos el estilo a la cabecera */
                document.head.appendChild(style); 
            
            window.print();        
            return ;
        }
    </script>
```

El problema es como manejar el codigo javascript para que me oculte las etiquetas que no quiero mostrar antes de llamar a la funcion de window.print();
mi pagina/vista MVC:

```
 @model Mvc4AppName.Models
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
//lo he colocado aquí y no lee la propiedad
<h2>Crear Cotizacion</h2>
<div class="hidden-print">
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post) ){
<table>
</table>
<script type ="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function () {
/*codigo de mi script*/
</script>
<div id="print_area">
 WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.vNames);
@grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
grid.Column("Codigo","Codigo "), 
..otros campos
grid.Column("Ptr","Generar impresion",format:@<text> @Html.ActionLink("Imprimir",null,null,htmlAttributes: new {onclick="imprime();"})</text>)
})

<div style="text-align:right">..</div>
}
```

Si lo ejecuto así, me invoca la instrucción de impresión antes de ocultar mis etiquetas

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más adecuado sería tener cargados y definidos los estilos de impresión desde antes, usando [media queries](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/estilos-css-para-imprimir-pautas-basicas-y-ejemplos.aspx) de acuerdo al medio (pantalla o impresora).

Sin embargo, puedes lograrlo como lo tienes ahora, solo esperando a que se cargue el estilo para enviar a impresión:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imprime() {    
        //document.cookie = "printer=" + 1;
        var style = document.createElement("link");
        // Escuchar carga de archivo
        style.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Imprimir solo hasta que se carguen los estilos
            window.print();        
        });
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.href = "../Content/printgeneral.css";
        ///* Añadimos el estilo a la cabecera */
        document.head.appendChild(style); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: gracias @Triby, eso funciona poniendo un boton, si lo hago desde mi ActionLink pasa algo extraño(se muestra un segundo y regresa a recargar toda la pagina).Creo que será mejor quitar esa columna de mi webgrid

Comment: sin embargo un detalle es que mi div a imprimir contiene una tabla, y al usar:" body > div:not(#print_area){ display: none;} " me oculta toda mi tabla generada por el webgrid

Comment: Dentro de la función agrega `event.preventDefault();` para anular el comportamiento normal de enlace o botón y evitar que se recargue la página.

Comment: En cuanto a lo que mencionas: _me oculta toda mi tabla generada por el webgrid_ hay que ver un ejemplo de la tabla, el estilo que estás cargando y qué elementos quieres ocultar.